# Adding subtrees to a tree

Tags: language-agnostic, tree

Suppose I have a tree X

```
                               a
                           b       c
                        d  e  f        g
```

and I want to add a long subtree Y to X

```
                           a
                           b
                           e
                           u
```

so X+Y would look like this.

```
                           a
                       b       c
                    d  e  f        g
                       u
```

How would one go about implementing such a tree concatenation?

Comment: It looks like ordinary adding of nodes to the tree, except that you're throwing out duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds to me like you're trying to insert a word into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). If that's what you're trying to do, you can start at the root of the trie and the beginning of the word and then process each character `x` - if there is no edge labeled `x` from the current node, create a new node and add an edge between them; then, in either case, follow the edge labeled `x` and move to the next character.